# track_visibility='on_change' functionality is not working in module

Tags: odoo

I have inherited hr.holidays module and create new module.Override write method of hr.holidays model and add some new functionality in this method.
Remove call super method from new write method using

> Existing
>
> - return super(hr_holidays,self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, contex=None)
>
> Repalce with
>
> - osv.osv.write(self,cr,uid,ids,vals,context=contex)

After this changes track_visibility log is not created in message_chatter box

Comment: For future readers: In Odoo version >= 14 `track_visibility` is no longer in syntax. Use `tracking` parameter instead. [link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/warning-on-odoo-14-with-track-visibility-184884)